# ggplot two geom points, combine both color scheme into one legend

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have two data set with a different range of y values, the y range of one data set includes the other. I'm trying to make separate plots for each data set, but combine the two legends, while keeping the color scheme separate.

I'm using `iris` dataset below, and created `iris2` as an example of the larger dataset.

```
iris2 <- iris
iris2$Sepal.Length <- iris$Sepal.Length*10
iris2 <- rbind(iris, iris2)
```

Then I plotted `iris` and `iris2` separately like below.

```
g1 <- ggplot(iris, aes(x=Petal.Length, y=Petal.Width, fill=Sepal.Length)) +
  geom_point(size=5, shape=21) + 
  scale_color_gradient(low="white",high="red", aesthetics="fill")
g2 <- ggplot(iris2, aes(x=Petal.Length, y=Petal.Width, fill=Sepal.Length)) +
  geom_point(size=5, shape=21) + 
  scale_color_gradient(low="red",high="blue", aesthetics="fill")
```

What I'd like to do is to keep the color scheme for `g1`, so that if I create a new legend for `g2`, the legend will still show `white` as `0` and `red` as `8`, then from `red` at `8` start changing colors until it becomes `blue` at `80`. (So that I can ultimately just keep the legend for `g2`, as it would show color schemes for both `g1` and `g2` data)

I tried to do this by using `scale_color_manual` like below but can't use it because this is forcing discrete values into a continuous scale.

```
scale_color_manual(c(0,max(iris$Sepal.Length),max(iris2$Sepal.Length)), values = c("white", "red", "blue"), aesthetics = "fill")
```

I also considered changing `fill=Sepal.Length` to `fill=as.factor(Sepal.Length)` to deal with that problem, but that would require me to manually type in dozens of colors to be used. Any advice?

(Just a note: in this reproducible example, `iris2` includes the same `Sepal.Length` values as `iris` so there would be no need to actually produce `g1`, but y values from my actual dataset do not overlap. That was just for me to create a quick reproducible example)

Comment: Your example data isn't ideal because as you note, points are overlayed on each other. Can I suggest this instead: `library(dplyr); iris2 <- iris %>% mutate(Sepal.Length = Sepal.Length * 10, Petal.Width = Petal.Width * 2) %>% bind_rows(iris)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could bind your datasets and use facets with `scale_fill_gradientn()` to make the color scale with the correct midpoint at the max of the first dataset (only relevant if you want a continuous color bar).

This approach involves using `scales::rescale()`, which is mentioned in the documentation for the `values` argument of `scale_fill_gradientn()`.

That could look something like:

```r
iris2 = iris
iris2$Sepal.Length = iris$Sepal.Length*10
iris2 = rbind(iris, iris2)

iris$name = "iris"
iris2$name = "iris2"

iris3 = rbind(iris, iris2)

library(ggplot2)

ggplot(iris3, aes(x = Petal.Length, y = Petal.Width, fill = Sepal.Length) ) +
    geom_point(size = 5, shape = 21)  + 
    scale_fill_gradientn(colors = c("white", "red", "blue"), 
                         values = scales::rescale(c(min(iris$Sepal.Length), 
                                                    max(iris$Sepal.Length), 
                                                    max(iris2$Sepal.Length))) ) +
    facet_wrap(~name) +
    theme(strip.background = element_blank(),
          strip.text = element_blank() )
```

[image]

You can change the `breaks` of the scale to make things more clear, as needed.

Even if you don't want to use facets, you could make a plot of the combined data and create the legend with `scale_fill_gradientn()` to use with your other plots.  One nice way to extract legends and combine plots and legends is with package **cowplot**.  See `cowplot::get_legend()`.

**For the legend size**

You can increase the physical hight of the legend via `legend.key.height` in `theme()`.

```r
ggplot(iris3, aes(x = Petal.Length, y = Petal.Width, fill = Sepal.Length) ) +
    geom_point(size = 5, shape = 21)  + 
    scale_fill_gradientn(colors = c("white", "red", "blue"), 
                         values = scales::rescale(c(min(iris$Sepal.Length), 
                                                    max(iris$Sepal.Length), 
                                                    max(iris2$Sepal.Length))) ) +
    facet_wrap(~name) +
    theme(strip.background = element_blank(),
          strip.text = element_blank(),
          legend.key.height = unit(1.5, "cm"))
```

[image]

If you don't have any 0 values you could also try working with the legend on the log scale, which can be done with `trans` in `scale_fill_gradientn()`, but it might take some fiddling to get things to look right.

Comment: This is great, thank you! I'm also wondering if it's possible to make the legend longer to make the color change stand out more obviously (as the white-red colors are only really focused on the bottom 10%) without manually creating more breaks but I've only ran across examples where people change the font sizes of the legend, not the size of legend itself. Do you know if there's an easy way to enlarge the legend?

Comment: @Jen I added an edit to show how you can use `legend.key.height` to increase the physical size of the legend vertically.